# How to handle '[ ] -' characters on JSqlParser

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, parsing, jsqlparser

I am using JSqlParser 3.0 and my query is  `SELECT * from [dev-testdb].dbo.EMPLOYEES`. I am trying to remove [] characters because JSqlParser 3.0 version is not supported for these characters.I guess 1.x does but I have to use 3.0.

After remove brackets, my query seems like `SELECT * from dev-testdb.dbo.EMPLOYEES` .
I am debugging my project and on this command

`final Statement statement = CCJSqlParserUtil.parse(sql);` 
I catch this exception

```
net.sf.jsqlparser.parser.ParseException: Encountered unexpected token: "-" "-"
    at line 1, column 18.
```

How can I fix this 3 characters when I parse with JSqlParser?

Comment: You have to have the brackets. A name like `dev-testdb` must be delimit identified. This is why you should avoid names that have that requirement.

Comment: There multiple issues regarding your issue on JSqlParser's Github repo. Try to check those issues: https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+Encountered+unexpected+token

Comment: Yes,  I just removed '[ ]' characters when there is no '-' character. But now I cannot remove them too. Is there any way support this query style ?

Comment: Sounds like the problem is the language, and it's lack of support of delimit identified objects, than the Query. Delimit Identifying objects is quite common, and if a language doesn't support that, it's (significantly) flawed, in my view.

Comment: @Larnu: in standard SQL you would have to write that as `"dev-testdb"` the square brackets are for array access in SQL. @bilinmeyenkarakter as SQL Server also supports standard double quotes for quoted identifiers, you could simply replace `[` and `]` with `"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an issue of **JSqlParser** but its **evolution**. :)

Bracketquotation was switched off by default, to support all kinds of array syntax, which uses in most cases square brackets as well. This change was introduced with **JSqlParser 3.0**.

> The array parsing is the default behaviour. Square bracket quotation has to be enabled 
>   using a parser flag (**CCJSqlParser.withSquareBracketQuotation**).

Here is the discussion: https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser/issues/677.

To activate this bracket quotation again use something like:

```
CCJSqlParserUtil.parse("select * from [mytable]", parser -> parser.withSquareBracketQuotation(true));
```

The lambda expression is used to somehow modify the used parsers configuration.